# Is there a Premiere Pro "command"+"\" function in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I work on a MacBook and use an iPad as a secondary monitor. Sometimes, when jumping between applications, the Adobe apps resize or reposition themselves out of my working screen area. In Premiere Pro there is a fast easy solution <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. This function maximizes the working window to fit the screen. Is there a similar function in Photoshop, or do I have to pray that moving the window to a different monitor and back 10 times will give me a grabbable edge.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Best guess is you have "Displays have separate Spaces" set in Mission Control. If you do that then any window you move to a different monitor will then be on a different Space to the main app. Spaces is not designed to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps <kbd>f</kbd> is what you are looking for. (yes, just the F)

- Hit it once and you get a full screen document with your desired pasteboard color and panels.
- Hit it again and you get a full screen document with a black pasteboard and *without* panels.
- A third tap brings you back to standard floating windows with panels.

I will point out though Photoshop has never really played ideally when you move documents between monitors. Especially if you position a document on two or more monitors at the same time.